# Why am I getting an error when trying to use Array.includes as the function for Array.filter in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Recently when working on a project in javascript I tried something similar to this snippet. I was surprised to find out it doesn't work and instead throws an error.

```
const test = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const something = [1, 2, 3, 4, ,5, 6, 7, 8].filter(test.includes);

console.log(something);

TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at includes (<anonymous>)
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:3:45
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:74:29)
    at Object.runInContext (vm.js:182:6)
    at evaluate (/run_dir/repl.js:133:14)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/run_dir/repl.js:116:5)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:274:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:261:11)
```

Is this a javascript bug or am I misunderstanding something here. The following snippets work fine:

```
const test = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const something = [1, 2, 3, 4, ,5, 6, 7, 8].filter(item => test.includes(item));

console.log(something);
```

And:

```
const test = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const someFunc = theThing => test.includes(theThing);
const something = [1, 2, 3, 4, ,5, 6, 7, 8].filter(someFunc);

console.log(something);
```

Working towards a more functional style of programming and point free when I see the patterns easily enough, this seems like an inconsistency.

Edit: This is not a duplicate. I don't need clarification on `This`, just on how it was handled in the context of the includes function specifically.

Comment: Passing `test.includes` breaks the relationship between the `includes` method and the object `test`. Wrapping it in a function like you did or using `.bind()` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `thisArg` of [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and the prototype of the function of the object.

```js
const test = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const something = [1, 2, 3, 4, ,5, 6, 7, 8].filter(Array.prototype.includes, test);

console.log(something);
```

**But [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) has a second parameter `fromIndex`, which is handed over by the filter function and that is the index, which may be unwanted.**

In this case, you may better use the direct style.

```js
const test = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const something = [1, 2, 3, 4, ,5, 6, 7, 8].filter(v => test.includes(v));

console.log(something);
```

Comment: The latter is what I ended up doing. I was just surprised it didn't work the way I was expecting it to. Your explanation makes sense though, thank you for th e clarification.

Answer (score 1):

`test.includes` evaluates to a reference pointing to a function, and through that its context (aka `this`) gets lost.

```
 const fn = test.includes;
 fn(1); // doesnt work
 fn.call(test, 1); // does work as you explicitly set `this`.
```

You can easily fix it by using the second parameter of `filter`,

```
 .filter(test.includes, test)
```